# Use encoder in service

Tags: php, symfony

I get the following error when I try to use an encoder in a service :

`Cannot instantiate interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface`.

Here is my code:

```
namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class Test
{

    public function encodePassword($username, $password)
    {    
        $passwordEncoder = new UserPasswordEncoderInterface();
        $encodedPassword = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($admin, $password);
        return $encodedPassword;
    }
}
```

I am using symfony 4.

Comment: Interfaces cannot be instantiated. Judging by the name, UserPasswordEncoderInterface is an interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To encode a password in Symfony, use the encoder factory. You can inject it in your own service by injecting an instance of `EncoderFactoryInterface` in your constructor (if you have autowiring enabled, Symfony will handle this automatically) and then use it as follows:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class SomeService
{
    /**
     * @var EncoderFactoryInterface
     */
    private $securityEncoderFactory;

    public function __construct(EncoderFactoryInterface $securityEncoderFactory)
    {
        $this->securityEncoderFactory = $securityEncoderFactory;
    }

    public function encodePassword(UserInterface $user, $password)
    {
        $encoder = $this->securityEncoderFactory->getEncoder($user);
        return $encoder->encodePassword($password, $user->getSalt());
    }
}
```

Note that we expect the User entity to have a salt. If you haven’t generated a salt yet, you should do so before encoding the password.

A simple approach for updating the user with a salt and a password might look like this:

```
public function setPassword(UserInterface $user, string $password)
{
    $user->setSalt(base64_encode(random_bytes(18)));
    $this->setPassword($user, $this->encodePassword($password));
}
```

Don’t forget to persist the entity afterwards.

Comment: Forgive me i'm learning, how can i call the service inside the Entity as you do it?

Comment: Nobody said something about using use services inside entities. This is an absolute antipattern.